# How to resize partition?

Tags: partitioning

So I finally got Windows to boot but I need to allocate space. When I try to resize the partion it won't let me. Do I need to unmount it?

EDIT: Or what happens if I format the part (including Ubuntu) and installed Windows over it? Doesn't sound like a good idea but I'm no expert.

Comment: Do you want to use dual boot if yes recommended to install windows first then install Ubuntu You can't re-size the mounted partition. http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the partition to resize needs to be unmounted. Most easy to use for you should be Gparted a grafical frontend for fdisk, is available during try live.

Yes. you shouldn't install windows after Linux or you have to reclaim the boot manager from windows.

Best is to run checkdisk (could be called slighty different, verifiy) and defrag on windows to make sure all windows file are in the begin of the partition, can be skiped on fresh windows install.

The Gparted documentaion can be found [here](http://gparted.org/documentation.php) for futher reference.